# Refactoring lambda to method for event

Tags: c#, events, lambda, refactoring, resharper

How to refactor a lambda event handler to the classical method using Resharper or Visual studio refactoring tools? The problem, apparently, because of closure. And it is not always possible to convert lambda event handler to the method.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it appears you answered your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but I did it about 2 minutes ago. (If you have re-sharper) Copy the code inside the lambda and then delete the method to just before += and then hit ctrl-alt-space and in the re-sharper dropdown select the CreateMethod option.  Now paste the code into the method that re-sharper has created

Comment: I miss that refactoring quite often, like an option in "Extract method" that would make a method from the lambda, provided it's not capturing anything.

Answer (score 0):

if the method signatures are correct, you can do an extract method on the body of the lambda and then inline the lambda.